# Not show Consumable, Non-consumable, Subscription in manage in app purchase

Tags: ios, ios7

i have created app id and enable in app purchase then i created app on i Tune then i click on manage in app purchase option  Consumable, Non-consumable, Subscription are not show please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Pressing Manage In App Purchase Button, there will be button called "Create New". Click on that you will get all the in-app purchase option.

Before that make sure you have agreed to all recent contracts.You must agree to the Developer Program License Agreement before you can access the Paid Applications agreement.

Here is some comments from Apple you can see when you click on "Create New" button :

"Select the In-App Purchase type you want to create. If a type is missing, make sure you have agreed to all recent contracts. The Legal user must go to the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" module on iTunes Connect to agree to the latest Paid Applications agreement. You must agree to the Developer Program License Agreement before you can access the Paid Applications agreement. To help ensure that your app is not vulnerable to fraudulent In-App Purchases, review the In-App Purchase Receipt Validation documentation."

[image]

Comment: Hi can i get prodect list as i added in my application in-app purchase without setup "Tax, Bank, Contact" in "Contracts, Tax, and Banking"

Comment: Yes you only need to review and agree - iOS developer License Agreement. Great now your problem is solved :)